# [1]+[2] != [1,2] (behavior of array union operator on non-associative arrays)

Tags: php, arrays, operators

`[1=>0]+[2=>0]` yields `[1=>0,2=>0]`. But is there any trick to use such syntax sugar for `[1]+[2]`. So `[1]+[2]` yeilds `[1,2]`?

**note**: My concern is about such syntax, not about other related PHP functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because **`+` is union operator. It does not append or merge.**

```
[1] is array(0=>1);
[2] is array(0=>2);
```

If you union it'll become `array(0=>1)` as `0` key already exists in the first array.

There is no syntactic sugar to do it. However, you can try this

```
[1]+[1=>2]
```

or in other ugly expression

```
[1]+[count([1])=>2]
```

Also syntactically `[1]+[2] == [1,2]` does not make sense at all.  Thats python thing.

Answer (score 5):

Use [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) instead. I stumped across so much of strange behavior of `+` used with arrays that I promised myself to never use it ever again.

Answer (score 5):

`+` is the array union operator, which will skip existing keys.

You want `array_merge()` which will concatenate them in your example (it does that for arrays with numeric keys).

Unfortunately for you, there is no way to overload the `+` operator to perform anything different.